# avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00 in arduino uno R3 the device is also no resetting

Tags: arduino

I've a arduino UNO R3 and it's causing the same problem but another uno r3 is not showing this problem while uploading and the reset button is also not working. i was working then sudenly one time it showed the above error and then till now .Plz tell what to do as there is no problem with the drivers or compatibility.

Comment: Have a look over at the Arduino site - eg. this thread: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1585/avrdude-stk500-getsync-not-in-sync-resp-0x00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Atmel ATmega328, which is the MCU in the Arduino, the `RESET` pin can be configured as a general purpose IO pin (PC6) by programming the `RSTDISBL` fuse bit, see §1.1.5 in the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8161.pdf). When this is done, the pin cannot be used as a reset input anymore.

If you accidentially programmed that fuse there's probably no way to get into the bootloader routine, and there's no way to use serial SPI programming to "un-program" that fuse.

In that case, you will need to use the "high voltage programming" to get your device back working. This can be done using, e.g., the Atmel [AVR-STK500](http://support.atmel.no/knowledgebase/avrstudiohelp/mergedProjects/STK500/Html/HVProgramming.html) or the ["Dragon"](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrdragon/avrdragon.pp_description.html).